# Representation of time expanded graph

Tags: c++, graph, time, boost

I want to build a time expanded graph with time discretization Dt that starts at t = 0 and ends at t = T where between the node (n1, t) and the node (n2, t')  is an arc if and only if (n1, n2) were connected in the original graph.

How can this be implemented in pseudo-code?
The problem I'm stuck on is how to pass from the original graph to the time expanded one.

(I use C++ and Boost libraries to write the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never too late to answer a question. This is how I did it, may help you guys.

So, what is time-expanded graph and how we do it? Check [this paper](https://smartech.gatech.edu/handle/1853/6492), not that sophisticated you thought.

Assume we had N nodes for static graph(that's say no time information) and we can and we did predict their moving at a time scale of T with interval of t(i), where t(i) is a function that indicate time interval after last time point. To simplify it, let t(i) = 1, for whole time scale.

As, the paper indicate, we need **three steps** to get time-expanded graph.

1. We add nodes for our graph, naming node name as 'node-${n}-t-${i}'.
2. We add temporal link, for every 'node-n-t-${i}' for each n in range(0, n, 1), with 'EdgeProperty.color = 0' to distinct with transmit link.
3. We add transmit link, for every edge what both exist in graph of t(i) and graph of t(i + k), with 'EdgeProperty.color = k'. Here I would explain some for the 'color' : it express the delay of one transmit which was stated in that paper, if you don't care this, just let k = 1.

Then, we done. For boost code, this is mine :

```
    // g_vec_ is vector of static graph
    // g_vede_m_ is vector of map of Vertex descriptor 
  118                     AdobDo_02(int node_number, int teg_layer_n, int max_range) {
  119                         // add all node to it node-n-t-i
  120                         Graph g;
  121                         map<string, VeDe> name2vd;
  122                         map<pair<string, string>, EdDe> pair2ed;
  123                         for (int n = 0; n < node_number; n++) {
  124                             for (int t = 0; t < teg_layer_n; t++) {
  125                                 stringstream ss;
  126                                 ss << "node-" << n << "-" << t;
  127                                 VeDe tmp_d = add_vertex(VertexProperties(ss.str()), g);
  128                                 name2vd[ss.str()] = tmp_d;
  129                             }
  130                         }
  131                         // add temporal link
  132                         // g_vec_ is vector of static graph
  133                         const int hypothetic_distance_of_temporal_link = 0;
  134                         for (int t = 0; t < teg_layer_n - 1; t++) {
  135                             for (int n = 0; n < node_number; n++) {
  136                                 stringstream ss;
  137                                 ss << "node-" << n << "-" << t;
  138                                 auto name_0 = ss.str();
  139                                 ss.str("");
  140                                 ss << "node-" << n << "-" << t + 1;
  141                                 auto name_1 = ss.str();
  142                                 auto vd_0 = name2vd[name_0];
  143                                 auto vd_1 = name2vd[name_1];
  144                                 auto tmp_ed = add_edge(vd_0, vd_1, EdgeProperties(hypothetic_distance_of_temporal_link, 0), g);
  145                             }
  146                         }
  147                         // for each layer add transmit link if distance_ of link 'a' of static upper layer graph is under max_range 
  148                         // and the distance of link 'b' of static lower layer graph is also under max_range
  149                         assert(g_vec_.size() >= teg_layer_n);
  150                         // assume that g_vede_m_ == teg_layer_n 
  151                         for (int t = 0; t < teg_layer_n - 1; t++) {
  152                             auto tmp_g = g_vec_[t];
  153                             auto tmp_g_other = g_vec_[t + 1];
  154                             for (int i = 0; i < node_number; i++) {
  155                                 for (int j = i; j < node_number; j++) {
  156                                     auto i_d = g_vede_m_[t][i];
  157                                     auto j_d = g_vede_m_[t][j];
  158                                     auto e_p = edge(i_d, j_d, tmp_g);
  159                                     auto i_d_other = g_vede_m_[t + 1][i];
  160                                     auto j_d_other = g_vede_m_[t + 1][j];
  161                                     auto e_p_other = edge(i_d_other, j_d_other, tmp_g_other);
  162                                     if (e_p.second && e_p_other.second) {
  163                                         auto ed = e_p.first;
  164                                         auto ed_other = e_p_other.first;
  165                                         if (tmp_g[ed].distance_ < max_range && tmp_g_other[ed_other].distance_ < max_range) {
  166                                             auto tmp_id_of_g = g_vede_m_[t][i];
  167                                             auto tmp_id_of_g_other = g_vede_m_[t + 1][i];
  168                                             auto tmp_jd_of_g = g_vede_m_[t][j];
  169                                             auto tmp_jd_of_g_other = g_vede_m_[t + 1][j];
  170                                             auto tmp_edge_of_g = add_edge(tmp_id_of_g, tmp_jd_of_g_other, EdgeProperties(
  171                                                         (tmp_g[ed].distance_ / 2) + (tmp_g_other[ed_other].distance_ / 2), 1), g);
  172                                         }
  173                                     } else {
  174                                         std::cerr << "Error: can't acess edge" << " : line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
  175                                         std::abort();
  176                                     }
  177                                 }
  178                             }
  179                         }
  180                     }
```